# Django admin not showing models - version 2.2

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 2.2. I don't know what I'm missing.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Efesto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Color, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....

    def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from estrategia import models

# Register your models here.
admin.register(models.Efesto)
```

Do I need anything else?

When I open the admin, I can't see the Efesto model there. The admin.py file is created automatically by the startapp command. The urls include

```
...
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

It has being a while since I code django, and this used to be enough to get the models registered. The app is included in settings.INSTALLED_APPS correctly. Any advice will help.

Comment: if admin site work nomally, try ```admin.site.register(models.Efesto)```

Comment: OMG how did I miss site.register ... thanks for your time. Hope this questions serves as a reference at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **admin.site.register(models.ModelName)** in order to show the model in django admin.
You can find more about this in their official documentation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/